# Hi guys, can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code??? I just started so its small and very basic yet I cannot point out what exactly is wrong

Tags: c

The code is as follows

```
int a=23
if (a>18){
    printf ("You can drive \n")
}
```

and when I run it, the error shown to me in the VS code is as follows-

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C Languange\" && gcc practice.exe.c -o practice.exe && "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C Languange\"practice.exe
practice.exe.c:2:1: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'if'
 if (a>18){
 ^~

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.457 seconds
```

As mentioned, this was my entire code-

```
int a=23;
;if (a>18){
    printf ("You can drive \n")
}
```

Comment: Haven't your book, teacher or other learning material told you that all statements must be terminated with a semicolon `;`?

Comment: The error posted refers to the first code (without any semicolons)... Would you be able to post what is _actual_ instead of two different versions?

Comment: And please [edit] your question to show us a proper [mre], the actual code that gives you the error. And *copy-paste* it, so you don't add other unrelated errors.

Comment: That is all the code  I got actually and the second one is the one that I tried with the corrected one as given to me by the error but here's the orignal code...

Comment: int a=23
if (a>18){
    printf ("You can drive \n")
}

Comment: Your code needs to be inside a function. You probably want to name it `main` since that is the entry point for an application. If the book didn't spell this out you would probably be better off with a different book.

Comment: That can't be "all the code"... There's no `#include <stdio.h>`, there's no `main` function. A good [mre] is something we can copy-paste and get the exact same error as you.

Comment: you need to write that to make the code work?

Comment: I am sry if I am being annoying but I really don't know all that, my teacher did not mention any of that

Comment: And I don't understand how can I give you the minimal reproducible example

Comment: If your teacher haven't told you about the `main` function, or shown it to you, then you need to have a talk with him or her. What other resources (books, tutorials) are you using to learn C? What do they say?

Comment: Um. I just have been trying to learn from youtube vids as the teacher won't be much of a help to me.

Comment: And can we talk somewhere else personally?

Comment: I could really use your help

Comment: # include <stdio.h>

int a=23
if (a>18){
    printf ("You can drive \n");
}

Comment: it still is showing me the same errror it did to me for the first code that I wrote

Comment: My advice: Get a good book and copy and paste its "hello world" program into your editor/compiler/IDE. Continue from there.

Comment: Any suggestions on the book?

Comment: See [this list on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/2057969). Start with *Head First C* or get the book by K. N. King. (my opinion)

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76795171/hi-i-just-started-c-on-vs-code-and-i-am-continuosly-getting-an-error-that-has-b#comment135388920_76795171) also your question? I've told you that you need to put your code in functions. BTW: Creating a new account to circumvent a temporary ban from asking new questions is very likely a violation of the TOS. Instead of asking nearly same question again, you should edit your existing question to get it reopened and reduce the number of downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just this once, I will show you how the program should look, and explain the different parts of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 23;

    if (a > 18)
    {
        printf("You can drive\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Now lets take each line one by one:

- `#include <stdio.h>`

  This isn't a C statement, it's a so-called *preprocessor directive*. It is an instruction to find and copy-paste the contents of the system *header file* `stdio.h` into the code.

  This specific header file is needed for the compiler to know about the `printf` function used later.
- `int main(void)`

  This is a function definition (implementation). It defined a function called `main`, which returns an `int` value and takes no arguments. All C statements that are not declarations or definitions must be inside a function.

  Execution of your program begins with a call to the `main` function.
- `{`

  This begins the block of code that implements the `main` function.
- `int a = 23;`

  This defines a variable named `a`, and initialize it with the value `23`. Normal statements in C *must* be terminated with the semicolon `;`.
- `if (a > 18)`

  This is a conditional statement. If the condition inside the parentheses is true then the next statement will be executed.

  The condition `a > 18` fetches the value of the variable `a`, and checks if it's larger than the value `18`. Since we just initialized `a` to have the value `23`, the condition will be true.
- `{`

  This starts a new block of statements. It is the block of code that will be executed if the condition is true.
- `printf("You can drive\n");`

  Call the `printf` function to print a string. The `\n` character in the string is the newline, and means a new line will be printed at the end of the string. Also note that this statement is also terminated by a `;`.
- `}`

  This closes the block of code for the `if` statement. Note that block-statements should not be terminated by a semicolon, the closing `}` also acts as a terminator.
- `return 0;`

  Because we defined the `main` function to return an `int` value, we need to actually return a value. That is what the `return` statement is doing. It will return *immediately* from the function, and in this case return the value `0`.

  It's normal for a program to return `0` if everything is okay. If there's an error, it's common to return a *small* positive integer value.
- `}`

  This closes the block of code for the `main` function, and marks the end of the program execution.

---

A good course, book or tutorial should have already told you all of this. If your tutorials haven't, then don't use them.

Unfortunately it's so easy to put up videos on Youtube, that there are millions of *bad* tutorials, and very hard to find something good. So my general advice is ti skip Youtube, and instead invest in some beginners books. [Here's a list of mixed books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Buying books is expensive, but in the long run that cost will be a good investment if you're really serious about learning C and programming.